# node sqlite return undefined although the data is inserted

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

I am try to insert data into sqlite3 database. The data is inserted but i get undefined as the return message instead of 'success'.

```
static async insert(firstname,lastname,username,role,phone,password,date) {
    const save_user = await db.run(
        ` INSERT INTO users
         VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) `,
        [this.lastID, firstname, lastname, username, role, phone, password, date],
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return {error:'error message'};
            }
            return {message:'success'};
        }
    );
return save_user
}
```

Comment: Your `insert` function doesn't return anything, maybe that's the reason you aren't getting your value.

Comment: And as a `console.log` doesn't return anything either, your callback in `db.run` is likely returning undefined.

Comment: i have also assigned the db.run to save_user and return save_user, yet i still get undefined

Comment: Could be useful to see the outer implementation then.

Comment: TryGhost/node-sqlite3 is what i am using. how do i fixed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [this `sqlite3` package](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3): this doesn't actually support promises, so you have to wrap `db.run()` manually:

```
static async insert(firstname,lastname,username,role,phone,password,date) {
  const save_user = await new Promise(resolve => {
    db.run(..., err => {
      if (err) {
        resolve({ error : 'error message' });
      } else {
        resolve({ message : 'success' });
      }
    });
  });
  return save_user;
}
```